Self не работает в функции в отдельном файле
Господа, прошу - помогите разобраться. Есть отдельный .py файл внутри которого такая функция:
Она центрует любые окна которые к ней попадают, чтобы знать какое окно ей передаётся параметр -> self.
def window_center(self) -> None:
    self.update_idletasks()
    width = self.winfo_width()
    frm_width = self.winfo_rootx() - self.winfo_x()
    root_width = width + 2 * frm_width
    height = self.winfo_height()
    titlebar_height = self.winfo_rooty() - self.winfo_y()
    root_height = height + titlebar_height + frm_width
    x = self.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - root_width // 2
    y = self.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - root_height // 2
    self.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(width, height, x, y))
    self.deiconify()

Внутри init класса окна в другом файле эта функция вызывается:
window_center(self)

Но я получаю ошибку:
window_center(self)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Подскажите, что я не правильно делаю?
P.S. Максимально полный воспроизводимый пример:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from ui_functions import *

class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Library catalogue')
        self.geometry('698x660')
        self.rowconfigure(index=0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(index=0, weight=1)

        style = ttk.Style()
        style.theme_use('clam')
        style.configure('mystyle.Treeview.Heading',
                        font=('Times New Roman', 12, 'bold'),
                        lightcolor='#242121', darkcolor='#242121')
        style.configure('mystyle.Treeview', font=('Times New Roman', 12),
                        lightcolor='#242121')
        window_center(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

Я не понимаю как передавать в функцию window_center - аргумент не self, чтобы она отцентрировала окно внутри себя...
Импортирую функцию в файл с классом следующим образом:
from ui_functions import *

Так как там несколько файлов и это всё пакет...

А как вы импортируете модуль внутрь другого файла? и почему self - эта функция - часть класса?

А как вы импортируете? Если import window_center, то это модуль получается. И вообще архитектура выглядит странно.

Обновил описание - внёс дополнения

"Класс выглядит следующим образом:" - это не класс, это просто функция с именем __init__. Класса у вас нет.

@Amgarak А это не тоже самое будет?

Похоже без полной структуры проекта и полного кода мы так и не разберёмся, это всё какие-то куски информации, которых недостаточно для понимания проблемы.

@CrazyElf добавил максимально воспроизводимый пример...

передавать в функцию window_center - аргумент не self, - а что вы хотите передать, с чем взаимодействовать? Я что-то потерялся..

В данном примере хочу передать в window_center корневое окно приложения, которое надо отцентровать. А далее передавать в него любые другие модальные окна приложения, которые тоже надо будет центровать

При этом, window_center это просто функция, не метод класса, видимо... Давайте начнём с простого. Скопируйте целиком функцию window_center в свой класс, и вызовите её (без передачи аргумента)

Да, это не метод класса т.к. я хочу ей пользоваться для других классов

Без понимания, что у вас в ui_functions ничего сказать нельзя.

Файл window_center с этой функцией, init_. В данный момент больше ничего нет

Вместо self, вы можете передать туда и сам объект, например так: window_center(app) ‍♀️ и тогда не нужно будет её в конструктор пихать.

Расшифруйте пожалуйста фразу "Так как там несколько файлов и это всё пакет..." Как пакет оформлен, что в пакете и т.д.?

@Amgarak Я попробовал: app = App() window_center(app) -> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

@CrazyElf Я планирую добавлять туда другие файлы, чтобы был пакет. Пока там один файл с этой функцией и файл init. В нем только это: all = ['window_center']

@Nasf странно, я имел ввиду что-то такое: тык
